# Java JTextArea KeyListener

Tags: java, swing, listener, jlabel, keylistener

When I pressed the ENTER my JTextArea starts a new row and I only want do to the doClick() method nothing else.
How should I do that?

```
textarea.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        button.doClick();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
});
```

Comment: don't use keyListeners at all (wondering how your code can possibly work: you have _focusable_ labels? How strange and user-confusing ...) - use keyBindings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `.consume()`:

> Consumes this event so that it will not be processed in the default
>   manner by the source which originated it.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
    e.consume();
    button.doClick();
    }
}
```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#consume%28%29)

Comment: Don't use a Key Listener. Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings.

Answer (score 8):

You should use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) with any `JTextComponent` in question. `KeyListeners` are way too low level from `Swing`'s perspective. You are using the concept which was related to `AWT`, `Swing` uses `KeyBindings` to do the same task with more efficiency and provides desired results :-)

A small program for your help :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class KeyBindingExample {

    private static final String key = "ENTER";
    private KeyStroke keyStroke;

    private JButton button;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    private Action wrapper = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            button.doClick();
        }
    };

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Key Binding Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

        textArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key);
        Object actionKey = textArea.getInputMap(
                JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).get(keyStroke);
        textArea.getActionMap().put(actionKey, wrapper);

        button = new JButton("Click Me!");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                System.out.format("Button Clicked :-)%n");
            }
        });     

        contentPane.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new KeyBindingExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```