# is there any way we can mask the value entering into jText area at runtime

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Is there any way we can mask the contents entering into JtextArea of java swing ?
My requirement is like at run time once the text area appears asking for input, whatever we enter there should appear as "*".
eg : I typed "Hello" from keyboard 
     It should appear as "*****".
I don't want to use JPasswordField!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [addKeyListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483813/java-jtextarea-keylistener). Also in function keyReleased you can put your conditions to make it more usable according to your scenario(s).

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

    public class App {
            String text= "";
            App(){
                JFrame f= new JFrame();
                final JTextArea area=new JTextArea();

                area.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

                }

                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                }

                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                   if(Character.isLetter(e.getKeyChar())) {
                      text = text + e.getKeyChar();
                      area.setText(text.replaceAll("[a-z]", "*"));
                   }

                   else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                      text = text + "\n";
                   }
                   System.out.println(text);
               }
            });
            area.setBounds(10,30, 200,200);
            f.add(area);
            f.setSize(300,300);
            f.setLayout(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            new App();
        }

}
```

Comment: This idea should work in my scenario. Thanks

Comment: Great to know. Can you make it as accepted answers. Thanks.

Comment: Apologize but again facing one issue :( If I am hitting "Enter" and again typing then contents is getting appended at first line itself. Is there any way to overcome this ?

Comment: You can put else if condition detecting enter key inside function keyReleased. I have updated my original answer regarding this.